# How do I set the default drop-down list?

Tags: cakephp

I encountered such a problem, CakePHP created a drop-down list, but I can not figure out how to set it to the default value, if the user did not choose that the system set the default value by itself. And how can you give it a `placeholder`, such as that there is no one inside to say "Choose"?

Tell me, please, in advance grateful.

At the moment the list has this kind of appearance

[image]

Code Listing of the drop-down list

```
$this->Form->select('progress', array([0 => 'One', 1=> 'Two', 2=>'Three']));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->Form->select('progress', [0 => 'One', 1=> 'Two', 2=>'Three'], ['empty' => '(Choose One)']);
```

Comment: Do not tell me, please, now if you do not choose progress, then there is an error `Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'progress' at row 1`